# Computer Vision API Batch Read File to extract text from multiple pdf and images

Tags: javascript, azure, computer-vision

we are  following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/javascript-hand-text
using the Computer Vision API - v2.0(POST BATCH READ FILE to send the pdf and images and get the extracted text
We are able to get the extracted text for both the pdf and image , but it is only for one image and one pdf at a time, Is there any azure computer vision api for multiple image/pdf processing with a single api call, Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry inr, at this moment we don't support process multiple image/pdf with a single api call. I will highly recommend you to provide your valuable suggestion in our User Voice channel: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430309-computer-vision-api

Thanks and sorry for all your inconveniences.